# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema en una consulta en php

```
$consulta="create temporary table tmp AS (SELECT DNI, COUNT(*) pendientes FROM ((SELECT DNI1 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>='2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI2 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>='2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI3 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>='2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI4 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>='2023-05-31')) tbl_tmp GROUP BY DNI);
create temporary table tmp2 AS (SELECT DNI, COUNT(*) anticipadas FROM ((SELECT DNI1 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>'2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI2 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>'2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI3 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>'2023-05-31') UNION ALL (SELECT DNI4 AS DNI FROM reservas WHERE fecha>'2023-05-31')) tbl_tmp GROUP BY DNI);
SELECT usuarios.DNI,nombre,intentos,activo,pendientes,anticipadas from usuarios LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp ON usuarios.DNI=tmp.DNI LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp2 ON usuarios.DNI=tmp2.DNI GROUP BY DNI;
DROP TABLE tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp2;";
//Consultamos días disponibles en día igual o superior a hoy
$resultado=mysqli_query($enlace,$consulta);
//recorremos los resultados
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
$dni=$rows['DNI'];$nombre=$rows['nombre'];$intentos=$rows['intentos'];$activo=$rows['activo'];
}
```

El caso es que si la consulta la realizo con phpmyadmin si me arroja resultados.

Comment: Esta misma pregunta está puesta 10000 veces en SOes. Cuando la conexión falla devuelve un `false`, que es lo que estás pasando al método después pensando que todo ha ido bien, pero no. Te ha dado un error, y como no estás comprobando si ha habido errores o no, no te has dado cuenta. Literalmente buscas "boolean given" en el buscador de SO y tienes decenas de preguntas sobre esto... has usado el buscador antes de preguntar? Porque según las reglas de SO es obligatorio demostrar que se ha investigado antes de abrir una pregunta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour].

Comment: y hay mas! https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysqli_fetch_assoc%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli_result%2C+boolean+given+in